# Starting work with FXyz library

Tags: java, javafx

Have problem with adding the library to the environment, mean after i included two jar files to the project : `JCSG.jar, poly2tri.jar` it steal doesn't work, 
do I have to do something else ? 
[image: ss]

Comment: Are you trying to build FXyz?

Comment: yes, would like to use this library in my project

Comment: I've downloaded the zip with the project, open it with NetBeans, clean and build, and it works fine. What error do you get?

Comment: As a following the steps from here : https://github.com/Birdasaur/FXyz there is nothing about building the project from zip, do i have to include also the src folder to my project ?

Comment: You need to compile and build `FXyzLib.jar`. For that, download the [zip](https://github.com/Birdasaur/FXyz/archive/master.zip) with the source code, open the project with NetBeans, clean and build it. Then you will be able to add `FXyzLib.jar` to your own projects.

Comment: i can not see the FXyzLib.jar anywhere, you mean : JCSG.jar, poly2tri.jar ?

Comment: Indeed, it is not in the zip, you have to build it with the sources

Comment: my point is if i can add it to existing project already ? I do not wanna start from beginning and copy everything, after icnluding this two .jar's should work fine.

Comment: Those two jars are dependencies required for FXyzLib.jar. You _need_ `FXyzLib.jar` and you _can not_ download it from the repo: you _need_ to download the sources and either build the jar or add the sources to your project.

Answer (score 0):

To compile this project, I would recommend the version from https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz which comes with updated Gradle dependencies, i.e., dependencies are downloaded automatically. No need to manually download dependencies.